# Waiting to move to a different team with no set date

Tags: promotion

I'm a junior tech worker who works at a company that works mostly with other businesses in various industries and technical setups.

Since joining, I have been in the same team, which is now more than a year, as of writing. In my team, we often use technology made by one particular vendor (important detail for later.) The team often works with many of the businesses that my company works with, at the same time. There are several team members that work exclusively on some of these client's business tickets, due to service agreements. The team members that work on these service agreement tickets are members of the team with the most experience. Several of my colleagues that started at the same time as me have been promoted more quickly than I have - this, I assume, is down to being on these projects and having prior experience, which I don't have.

In the past few months I, and several other team members, were told that we were going to be moved on to other teams, that used technology by other vendors, and in order to make the transition more smooth and to show that we were all competent with the other vendor's technology, I would need a certificate by the vendor. I achieved and received the certificate, but have now been told that I won't be moving to the team I thought I would. At the same time, most of the other members of the team that were expected to move at the same time as me, have started that transition, some having completed their move already. I have been told on numerous occasions that I will move to one of several teams, which use either of the technology vendor's tech, but without any details beyond "you *may* move to this team."

Currently I feel as though I am stuck in limbo, without a date when I will move, if I will move. In the meantime, while I wait, I'm up-skilling.
Should I be worried at all at the waiting period?

Comment: Were you given any reason for not moving? Were your colleagues that did move more senior?

Comment: Have you discussed this with your supervisor/manager?  Generally there are reasons for things like this and it may be totally unrelated to your performance.  When in doubt, ASK!

Comment: Sometimes company reorgs do take months. Talk to your manager; they will tell you either to continue upskilling or to go back to working on what you were doing before this move was proposed.

Comment: @PM77-1 I had a 1-2-1 with an internal recruiter (for the team I was meant to go to), he asked for an honest opinion on how I felt about some of the technologies the other team used. I rated myself a low score due to not having much experience or the required cert. The internal recruiter said they (the client business) were looking for someone with more experience, which came across very confusingly!
For clarity, these other colleagues that moved are mostly not more experienced than I am, they may only have a marginal bit more experience than I do (a year or two)

Comment: @jwh20 I don't believe it's due to performance - in my last annual review, I actually received a small raise, and a good review! I've been picking up all work that I can but at this stage I'm basically doing the scraps from any project I can get my hands on.

Answer (score 1):

Should you be worried? Let me presume the worst-case scenario, that is (without any prejudice or malice) you are the least competent person on your team. Other people have demonstrated better competence and they got called up to the other team first - Even if we presume this (and again, not saying this is true - just using it to highlight a hypothetical) - You are still in your original team, earning your current Salary, doing your original work.

You've not lost anything.

Now, does the Team change come with a change of Salary or different perks or some other change in your reward package - then I might consider having a sit down with my Manager and saying:

"I'm feeling passed from pillar to post and overlooked, The company asked me to get certified for Vendor X, I did so and I am looking forward to working with the Team that handles Vendor X issues. Movement to this Team is good for my personal and professional growth due to *reasons* (Vendor X dominance in market, Job Title, responsibility etc.) and I'm looking forward to the increased remuneration package that comes with being in that Team. I'd like the company to outline a roadmap, with dates as to when I can transition into this team."

You are absolutely right to be annoyed at being kept in a state of Limbo - sometimes, especially with larger corporate entities - processes can start and then someone in the Managerial Sphere gets cold-feet or something unexpected comes along and things change/go on hold - I've been there countless times, it's irritating - and you can ask for clarification, sometimes they won't be able to give all the details and you have to accept that - however if you really feel aggrieved at this and you've asked for clarification or a timeline and you are getting no engagement from the Company, then it's time to dip your toe into the datin.. I mean Job Market and see what your new-found skills will bring you.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's be clear and understand that this is business.  Not only that, but you are in tech which can pose some very fluid situations at times that require shifting of resources with very little notice.  It sounds like you may have fallen victim to such a scenario.  However, understanding this is all part of the learning and maturing process as a business person.

With that said, if you still have concerns you should not be afraid of speaking with your supervisor and, if you don't get the answers you need, you should not be afraid of escalating those concerns up the chain of seniority.  A trend I've personally experienced is that many people in business seem almost terrified to speak with their boss regarding circumstances that might push them out of their comfort zone.  In this case, you clearly suspect you may have been mistreated or singled out.  Therefore, it's completely reasonable that you might ask your boss for a 15 minute conversation and just inquire about why the decisions were made.  The answer to those questions may offer you some solace, or they may make you realize you are in the wrong place.  Either way, asking is the correct thing to do.  One of the worst things you can do is do nothing, in which case you will sit around day after day growing more discontent simply because you chose not to pursue answers to your questions.

I hope this helps.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this many times over my career and there can be a variety of reasons for it. There can be legitimate business reasons such as needing to keep you on the current team for some big project to illegitimate reasons where they may not appreciate your skill set and are just paying you lip service.

Speak to your manager and try and get a more objective reason for the delay. Remind him/her about your certifications and up-skilling for the new challenge and how excited you are to take it on. See what their reaction is and try and get a more definitive timeline.

If you find yourself not moving and your frustration has grown too high, then it might be time to start looking for a position with a new company where you can potentially use your new skills. There is nothing wrong with moving on when you become stagnant with a company that doesn't seem invested in helping you in your career.